# Insert div after </ul> in wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a "clear"

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

after the  in wp_nav_menu.  I've read all kinds of answers to similar things using Walker classes, but that seems like overkill for just adding one line. I'm not trying to change menu structure.

Is there a simpler way to add this? or if Walker is the best way, would someone mind showing me how?  since I'm trying to do something different than most walkers, I'm having trouble sifting through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without extra HTML:

```
ul::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

`::after` is a pseudo-element

I'm assuming here that's what your `.clear` class is for :)

Comment: Thanks! I owe you an ice cream cone! I knew there had to be a simple way.